# Unable to pass json array tree as jquery method parameter

Tags: jquery, json

I have a following json array tree

```
 {"arrayTree":[{
   "root":"0",
   "id":"19",
   "name":"Rose",
   "childs":[{
                "root":"19"
                "id":"22",
                "name":"Ceema",
                "childs":[{
                             "root":"22",
                             "id":"49",
                             "name":"Chandar"

                          }]
        },
        {
            "root":"19",
            "id":"23",
            "name":"Ben"
        }]
}]}
```

my jquery function is:

```
   function demo(m) {
    var j = jQuery.parseJSON(m);
    var c = Object.keys(j).length;
        for(var i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        if(Object.keys(j)[i] == "[object Object]") {
              var v = Object.keys(j)['childs'];
              demo(v);
          }
          if(Object.keys(j)[i] != "[object Object]") {
              alert(Object.keys(j)[i]);
          }
    }
}
```

Here variable m is json array tree. But this is not working

Note: M using codeigniter

Comment: If it's not a string can you do it?

Comment: Why would it being a string prevent it from being passed?

Comment: I have put this json array tree in a variable called $map and from view m calling that jquey method as <button onclick="demo('<?php $map ?>')">Click</button>

Comment: Its not working this way

Comment: Can you please edit your post to show the function?

Comment: `<button onclick="demo('<?php $map ?>')">` - now imagine how that looks in the served page with all those double-quotes inside single-quotes inside double-quotes. That's the source of your problem. You will have more success assigning the JSON as an object-literal in a `<script>...</script>`, then attaching the click handler in javascript.

Comment: please explain a bit how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `<button onclick="demo('<?php $map ?>')">Click</button>` doesn't work is due to double-quotes (containing single-quotes) containing double-quotes. The single-quotes are fine but HTML parser will be confused by unescaped double-quotes inside double-quotes.

The workaround is quite simple.

As JSON is just a strict subset of what can be written as a javascript object-literal, your `<?php $map ?>` can stand wherever you would hard-code an object-literal.

Therefore, the following should work :

```HTML
<head>
...
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    $("#demo").on('click', function() {
        var myObject = <?php $map ?>;
        demo(myObject);
    });

    // *** or ***

    $(function() {
        $("#demo").on('click', function() {
            demo(<?php $map ?>);
        });
    });
});
</script>
...
</head>

<body>
    ...
    <button id="demo">Click</button>
    ...
</body>
```

Thus, the javascript interpreter will create a javascript object that mirrors you PHP variable `$map` and pass it to 
`demo()`.

Comment: " its not working" doesn't help me. I need to know more, eg is there an error message in the console?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.......yes i was getting error in console and was because jquery was defined at the bottom and i called this function at the top

Answer (score 0):

Look at this link

http://www.elated.com/articles/json-basics/

I'm not entirely certain where your JSON object is coming from, but in PHP you have to set it up as actual arrays rather than a typical JSON format. So it'd look something like this:

```
$arrayTree = array(
                 "root" => "0" ,
                 "id" => "19" ,
                 "name" => "Rose" ,
                 "childs" => array(
                                 a whole bunch of nested arrays...
                  )                                 
);

$map = json_encode($arrayTree) ;
```

Then in your JavaScript function, since you're using jQuery, use `parseJson()` on the object to translate that into a JavaScript object. You can then call everything from that object.

Also, in your `onclick="demo('<?php $map ?>')"` make it `demo(<?php echo $map ?>)`.

Comment: I did this in controller and passed $map to view and i also removed single quotes but still its not working